# How to implement an S-estimator

Tags: r, regression, least-squares

I'm trying to implement an MM-estimator in python. I have a working implementation of an M-estimator [statsmodels.RLM](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/examples/notebooks/generated/robust_models_1.html)  - which is implemented as an iteratively re-weighted least squares algorithm. I am struggling to implement the initial S-estimator, my understanding is that an S-estimator is an M-estimator of scale however none of the R packages ([mass.rlm](https://github.com/cran/MASS/blob/master/R/rlm.R), [robustbase.lmrob](https://github.com/cran/robustbase/blob/master/src/lmrob.c), [robust.lmRob](https://github.com/cran/robust/blob/master/R/lmRob.q)) I've found seem to implement this as an iteratively re-weighted least squares problem. My question is, can an S-estimator be implemented via iteratively re-weighted least squares or if not, what algorithm is used for this problem?